# which way is effective to store images into database using JSP through html?

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, struts

I want to store images into database using java server pages or struts via html.
time complexity and space complexity should be as less as possible.

which way is effective to store images into database using java server pages through html?
how to do that too?
is there any simple coding using Struts 2.1 for this task

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/docs/file-upload.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact need, but What I suggest is instead of storing images in DB, just store name of the images as say "abc.png" in table and store the actual image in one folder and make that image folder where you are storing as configurable in properties file.

Now you can read property file and get path then just give name of image like

```
 pathYouGetFromProprtyFile + File.seperator + imageNameYouGetFromDB
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: you people can share code for this
one html or jsp program for dynamically store images and another jsp program to save image into database simplest coding...

Comment: you can give a try by simple search on google and you will see that  many sites give you ready made code, which is your basic intention.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to convert the image to bytearray or BLOB/CLOB data format and store it in database. 
From web tier you can use fileupload to upload the image, store it in temp server location. Change it to ByteArray and save it in database either using JDBC or hibernate.
Hope it will help you!!!!